# Improving hints for CSS shorthand properties in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, intellisense

When it comes to specifying shorthand CSS properties within a CSS stylsheet using Visual Studio Code (e.g. such as `border`, `margin` or `background`) and I can never remember sequence of individual properties for the shorthand property.

When I mouse over say a `background` property in VSCode, I get:

[image: Visual Studio Code showing mouse over hint for <code>background</code> CSS property]

It would be more useful if I got something that included information on what values the property requires, such as the following taken from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp):

```
background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;
```

Is there a way to get this information directly with Visual Studio Code, so I don't have to go look it up elsewhere? Is there a extension that can provide this information?